# SwiftUI Full Keyboard Access

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, accessibility, ios-simulator

I have a 2 part question:

- I am implementing some custom controls and want to make sure they are
  correctly navigable when "Full Keyboard Access" is enabled in iOS
  settings. I am able to successfully navigate the UI with keyboard but
  I want to customise the focus UI. Currently it shows a blue
  background on the entire control but I would like to customise the
  look of the component that is currently in focus. The effect I am looking for is similar to what you can get with `.accessibilityPath` property in UIKit.
- I am unable to test this on iOS Simulator (Xcode 12 and 13). Nothing
  happens when I turn the "Full Keyboard Access" on in simulator
  settings app. Is there a way to test this on simulator instead of the
  device?

Minimum Deployment target = iOS 13
Swift 5.0
Xcode 12 and 13

Answer (score 1):

There is **isFocused** environment value, but it is only available on iOS 15. There is also **accessibilityShowButtonShapes** environment value that you need to check to highlight button borders.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize this in UIKit using focus methods like `didUpdateFocus` (as described in the Full Keyboard Access WWDC video), but you cannot do it in SwiftUI. I confirmed this during one of the WWDC Accessibility Q&A session with Apple's Accessibility Engineers: there are currently no hooks for Full Keyboard Access focus in SwiftUI.

On the other hand, the default focus provided by the OS is customizable by the user in Settings > Accessibility > Keyboards > Full Keyboard Access > High Contrast, which will replace the pale blue tint with a sufficiently visible focus indicator. You can't customize the shape, but if you're primarily concerned about whether it is sufficiently contrastive, this is determined by the user